# Show $x^2+2x+1\equiv 27 \;\text{mod}\; 61$ is solvable and find the number of solutions.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'll show how far I have got: $$x^2+2x+1\equiv 27 \;\text{mod}\; 61$$ $$(x+1)^2\equiv 27\; \text{mod} \; 61$$ So we need to find the Legendre symbol value for $$\begin{pmatrix} 27\\ 61 \end{pmatrix}$$ $$=\begin{pmatrix} 3\\ 61 \end{pmatrix}^3$$ $$=\begin{pmatrix} 61\\ 3 \end{pmatrix}^3=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 3 \end{pmatrix}^3, \text{as}\;\; 61\equiv 1\; \text{mod}\; 4$$ $$=1  $$ Hence solvable. Now I have no idea how to go about finding the number of solutions. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [61 is prime](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/61_(number)), $\Bbb{Z}/61\Bbb{Z}$ is a field, so the equation has at most 2 solutions since a quadratic polynomial over a field has at most 2 zeros. Since $0^2\ne 27 \pmod{61}$, and since $\left(\frac{27}{61}\right)=1$ as you mentioned, $27 = u^2$ for some $u\ne 0$. Then either $x+1=u$, or $x+1=-u$, so either $x=u-1$ or $x=-u-1$. These are both solutions to the equation and necessarily distinct since $u$ and $-u$ are.
Thus there are exactly two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about this with trial and error. Try 61+27 = 88, and see if that's a square. It's not, so try $2\times 61 + 27 = 149.$ Nope. Eventually, you will get $x=23$ and $x=36$.